# How do build a composite or template control in ASP.Net MVC, or the equivelant?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

In our current ASP.Net Webforms application we have several composite/template server controls that only exist for a common look and feel.  For example, we have a panel control that has a title, a place for buttons related to the contents of the panel, and of course the contents.  How is this best accomplished in MVC?  RenderPartial doesn't get done what I need here.  Should I still be using the same controls, but just on a view page?  These controls don't really do anything on postback, they are only there for a common look and feel.

More Info:

We have a control in Webforms that implements ICompositeControl.  We have a few properties on this control like Panel (type Panel), Buttons (again type Panel which would hold buttons) and a property Title of type string.  Visually it looks like

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Templated partial views](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/asp-net-mvc-and-the-templated-partial-view-death-to-ascx/) is the way to go.

Comment: That looks promising.  How do you pass in multiple, discreet sections of HTML to be displayed in the partial?

Comment: I gave you +1 because we are going to use something like that for another issue, but we actually ended up building a different solution for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little hazy about the exact requirements here but i'f I understand this correctly then you want a control that has say title information with variable content such as static text, controls, images etc etc.

If I had to have a control that acted as a container for content, no matter what that content was, I think I'd consider a Html Helper that I could pass information to and it could make the assessment on what content to render.

It could then either call another helper, render a partial view or whatever.