# ASP.NET MVC Templated Control

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am currently building an ASP.NET MVC site after years of being in the Web Forms world (and taking a bit of getting used to!).

I have an admin dashboard which has several area's contained in boxes which can be collapsed etc. The basic layout of the box is the same for all - the only difference is the content inside the box. I don't really want to repeat the box code over and over (talking only about front end code here). What I would normally do in the Web Forms world is create a control with template region for the content (i.e http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/06/04/Supporting-Templates-with-ASP.NET-User-Controls.aspx)

This question is pretty similar to my scenario [How do build a composite or template control in ASP.Net MVC, or the equivelant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799827/how-do-build-a-composite-or-template-control-in-asp-net-mvc-or-the-equivelant). The top answer in the referenced question points to this article http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/asp-net-mvc-and-the-templated-partial-view-death-to-ascx/ which I guess would work but seems somewhat of a hack. What is the best way to achieve this in MVC? How do others handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sharing is in the layout, use **master** (a concept from web forms).

If it is in the content then use [Display/Editor Templates](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html).